# Convert hour minute values into UTC hour minute value from the provided timezone

Tags: java, java-time

```
public static String convertTimeInUTCByTimezone(String hour, String minute, String meridiemIndicator, String timezone, TimeFormat timeFormat)
  {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonth(), localDate.getDayOfMonth()),
                    LocalTime.parse(hour + ":" + minute + " " + meridiemIndicator, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"))
            ), ZoneId.of(timezone));
    TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
    ZonedDateTime utc = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(TIMEZONE_UTC));
    String str = utc.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormat.getPattern()));
    return str;
  }
```

This is my code I am using but the problem is the conversion for timezone "Europe/Volgograd" on my local is 1 hour ahead as that on my server. The same code behaves differently on local and server.

Comment: what java version (including build number) are you on? There were timezone changes in 2020: https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-volgograd-time-zone-2020.html, those changes were addressed in 8u291

Comment: Could you perhaps develop a [mre], please?

Comment: If the root cause is indeed the changes in the Europe/Volgograd time zone (which sounds very likely), you may update the time zone data in your Java installation using the [Timezone Updater Tool — Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/tzupdater-readme.html). Similar options exist for non-Oracle Java releases.

Comment: Note: I think `LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), localDate.getMonth(), localDate.getDayOfMonth())` can be replaced by just `localDate`.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov The issue is also reproducible for Africa/Juba timezone

Comment: Africa/Juba? Probably a similar explanation. [South Sudan Switches Time Zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/south-sudan-time-zone-2021.html).